# PHP Fatal error : Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I know this is a common error but I just can't figure this out and I've had enough head scratching.

When ever I run this code to update a database entry I get this error.

```
ERROR : Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

$firstName = "Jack";
$username = "JackTrow";

$query = "
    UPDATE users SET
    first_name=?
    WHERE username=?
    ";
    $statement = $DatabaseHandler->getMysqli()->prepare($query);
    $statement->bind_param('ss', 
    $firstName, $username);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->free_result();
```

I just don't see how this is possible as this code works fine on my localhost however when uploaded onto my vps it flags up this error. Any possible ideas?

Comment: What is the type for $statement? It's possible the prepare() function isn't working (for whatever reason, bad DB connection, etc) and returning a FALSE.

Comment: Since it sounds like a server config error, check the output of phpinfo() and see if you have the mysqli module installed.

Comment: This code runs on my site and all other database communication works, and it is a mysqli statement

Comment: Before the bind_param() call, add a 'echo $statement->errno' and see what the value is. Non-zero means an error occurred prior to the bind_param() function call.

Comment: I did that and I get the following notice, Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: That means your prepare() function is returning FALSE. Your query is malformed or the DB connection has an issue.

Comment: Before the bind_param call, add `echo $DatabaseHandler->getMysqli()->error`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question it was down to the mysql user privileges. It allowed selecting, deleting etc.. but not updating. Silly mistake but its a hard one to spot.

I discovered this by first looking over the code and checking for any syntax errors but they couldn't be any as it worked on my localhost machine but not my online server. With this the case it must be to do with my server setup or connection problem; problems with the code were ruled out.

It couldn't be the connection as other queries were working fine, this had me even more stumped. So i decided to try another query with the same code, I tried to select from the database instead of updating and it worked. This meant it could only be one thing which was the mysql user privileges. When you connect to the database you connect using a mysql user and you can allow/disallow what type of queries it is allowed to do; i didn't add to allow update queries. So i logged into cPanel and changed it to allow it and it worked!

Comment: If you add how you discovered that I'm sure someone else down the line would be very appreciative.

Comment: I was thinking about adding that in but was thinking people would just want to get straight to the answer but you're right; there is method to the madness and its just as good as the answer.

Comment: Those who look to learn but not understand aren't welcome here. I commonly downvote answers that don't teach but simply provide a solution. There's plenty of crappy 'developer forums' out there that provide snippets of code as solutions with no explanation. You can easily see who visits them because there answers are always "Can you try this: [big block of code]"

Comment: Its almost compulsive for me to understand not just learn, I say it to everyone that I feel needs to hear it; I'll change my ways from this moment on within answering questions on stackoverflow, i just never quite clicked on within this context.

Comment: Did you ever do `echo $DatabaseHandler->getMysqli()->error` after the prepare statement?

Comment: I looked for a error before preparing, but since I was testing for an error from the statement object is just flagged another error. I never tried that code specifically and Its hard for me to do it now but I guess it would of just give to same error I was getting as that was the error to the code; it was just hard to gather from the error.

Comment: I busted my head for nearly two hours on this very subject. It was down to user permissions. Check the simple things first! And thank you for this post!

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> mysqli_prepare()/MySQL::prepare() returns a statement object or FALSE if an error
>   occurred.

Sounds a like a connection issue, since it works "fine" on your local machine.
To ensure that, you can test it like,

```
$statement = $DatabaseHandler->getMysqli()->prepare($query);

if (is_object($statement)) {
   // Here it returned Statement object
   // So it's kinda safe to call bind_param()
   $statement->bind_param('ss'.....      
} else {
   // Seems like its FALSE now, because of connection issues
   die('Jeez, connection issue')
}
```

Comment: The script returns "Jeez, connection issue" so they must be a connection problem, but when I just query and select data from the database its all good; oh i think I just figured it out, it must be the privileges I set to the database user, only explanation.

Comment: Yeah, the only possibility then is privileges and only, sure

Comment: Yesss! it works, changed the privileges to allow updating and works like a dream, was wondering why this query wasn't working and other were, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using MySQLi:

```
bind_param()
```

You might want to check out PDO, you can use the `bindParam` instead.

It would go like:

```
$statement->bindParam ( 1 , $firstName );
$statement->bindParam ( 2 , $username );
```

Comment: I tried that out of curiosity as got the same error, Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object

Comment: -1 [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) most certainly *does* exist. It does not exist on *PDO* classes, but it does in the **MySQLi** interface.

Comment: @cwallenpoole - shoot - you're right, I've adjusted it accordingly.

Comment: Before switching to PDO, it pays to make sure your web host actually has it installed

Answer (score 0):

I believe you ar using pdo right?
Try this way

```
/* Execute a prepared statement by binding PHP variables */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->execute();
```

Comment: This statement is a mysqli not pdo, sorry for not including that in the question

Comment: No, he's using **MySQLi**

Answer (score 0):

First of; always try to run the query in your localhost to see if it runs without errors and also, always make sure the names of the fields in your table correspond to what you have in your query